# ASP.NET Core - http 206 status code in Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way in Swagger for ASP.NET Core to simulate a http 206 partial content ?

I have a scenario when a user will download a lot of data and I want to describe and test this scenario in Swagger.

I used `ProducesResponseType` annotation to express more information about my API resource, however I don't know how to do it for http 206 request

```
[HttpGet("Files/{id:guid}/{name}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PhysicalFileResult), 200]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PhysicalFileResult), 206]
public async Task<PhysicalFileResult> GetFooFile(guid id, string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
=>PhysicalFile(Foo(paramters));
```

Comment: I don't think you need to (or even should...) advertise HTTP 206 in your Swagger file: it's contingent on the remote client making a ranged-request, while Swagger/OpenAPI definitions are not expressive enough to encompass that behaviour... (also, support for HTTP 206 and ranged responses is implicit in File Responses, IMO). I'm more concerned at your lack of declared resposne types for 400, 404, etc.

Comment: interesting thanks @Dai for the informatio
FYI I already declared 400 and 404 but for  the sack of exemple I didn't put them